# choosing which job will execute in multijob phase, from env variable, in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I have a multijob, and I want at phase jobs, at job name, to select the actual job name, from a variable, and more specific from an environmental variable.
I tried, among many other things, the following:

[image]

This should have been working, because I cross checked that `$JOB` exist and with a value at `$WORKSPACE?build.properties`.

Any ideas? 
jenkins version is 2.73.3

Comment: The image upload didnt work

Comment: @Frankenstein. Something must be wrong in your browser.cross checked in multiple browsers and os